# query optimization / data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query which pulls some data from table A and table B.  there's a one to many relationship between the two where table A is the one.  i'm not super good with mysql, and was wondering if i could perform this query better?  the loop to fetch the data was the only way i could figure out how to arrange it all for display purposes since the query duplicates the info in table A for every unique row in table B.  was wondering if anyone could show me a better way?

```
$sql = "
  SELECT core.`id` AS attribute_id, core.`gender` as attribute_gender , core.`order` as attribute_order, core.`name` as attribute_name, coreval.`id` AS value_id, coreval.`value` as value_name
  FROM  `core_attributes` core
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  `core_attribute_values` coreval 
  ON core.id = coreval.attribute_id
  WHERE core.active = 1 
  ORDER BY attribute_order
";

try {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array(':agency_id' => $agency_id));

  $result = array();

  while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $result[$row['attribute_id']]['attribute_id'] = $row['attribute_id'];
    $result[$row['attribute_id']]['attribute_gender'] = $row['attribute_gender'];
    $result[$row['attribute_id']]['attribute_order'] = $row['attribute_order'];
    $result[$row['attribute_id']]['attribute_name'] = $row['attribute_name'];
    $result[$row['attribute_id']]['values'][$row['value_id']] = $row['value_name'];
  }
  return $result;
}
```

**edit**: removed a part of the query unrelated to my question

Answer (score 1):

Use mySQL's

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

statement to learn, [how mySQL executes your statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html). From there, go ahead and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

the `while` loop can be managed with a further `foreach` loop, making it a little simpler.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    // Set $id for each iteration of the while loop
    $id = $row['attribute_id'];

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

        // Set $result to the corresponding key => value pairs
        $result[$id][$key] = $value;

    }
}
```

Your mySQL statement looks ok to me!